# Bootstrap max-width columns responsive

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, text-align

I am trying to code a section of a one-page responsive Bootstrap design that has two side-by-side columns of text. The designer wants these two columns to have a max-width, but once it reaches its max, it is no longer centered (as the rest of the content continues to be responsive).

Is there a way around this to still have the two columns of text centered?

Edit: Here is a link to what the code looks like: http://www.bootply.com/119539

Comment: Please share a link to test website, or a fiddle or at least a screenshot.

Comment: Sorry about that. I added the code in my original post.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here try this **[Bootply](http://www.bootply.com/119543#)**. Is this what you are looking for?

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-lg-12">
            <h2 class="center-block">How We Work</h2>

    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4 col-lg-offset-2">
        <p class="text-justify center-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Fusce quis nulla nec lacus condimentum molestie.</p>
    </div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">
        <p class="text-justify center-block">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. .</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

---

```
h2.center-block{
    text-align:center;
}

p.text-justify{
 max-width:400px;
}
```

**NOTE:** You can use `col-lg-offset-2` to shift the div by 2 columns.

Comment: I didn't use proper classname and used whatever was available. Sorry about that.

Comment: Wow, thanks! That looks great! Is there any way to maintain the 30px gutter spacing between the two columns and still keep it all centered like that?

Comment: Yeah. I used `center-block` on `<p>` remove that and float first one to right and second one to left;

Comment: For some reason when I try and implement it, it doesn't work on my site: http://watchcampfire.com/pre

Comment: And your text isn't justified because you used `<cufon>` on every word. Plus I can't see, where you used `max-width`

Comment: Thanks! Yeah, I noticed the justification issue. I'll have to fix that. Also, max-width is on col-lg-4. Should I place it elsewhere?

Comment: Yes. Specifically on paragraphs. bootstrap columns work because they have a specified width in %. You shouldn't override that.

Comment: Buddy could you mark this as correct if your problem is solved ?

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I just have one last question. Can anything be done about this in-between. I think it's between col-md and col-sm that I get this: http://imgur.com/3eCDzHH This is the code I'm using: http://www.bootply.com/119779

Comment: add col-xs and you should be fine

Comment: For some reason it's still doing that, even after adding it: http://watchcampfire.com/pre2

Comment: You're using col-xs-12 means it will occupy whole row. Use col-xs-6

Comment: If you use col-xs-6, NO they won't stack. Seems like I might have to charge you after this for consultation. :)