# Trouble with responsive Max Width column in Bootstrap

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to get this page to look nice on bigger displays:
http://clccedarrapids.com/christian-theology/Christian-Theology.html

What I want to do is set a maximum width for the large article on the right (It is akward to to read that wide of an article on large displays). I had some success with [this solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/22233766/bootstrap-max-width-columns-responsive) when I used plain text but when I include the article with ssi instead of the plain text it simply stops working (I think because that solution requires a custom p class and my include also uses custom p classes. Is there an easy solution to this?

Comment: setting your left container class to `col-md-9 col-lg-10` and the right to `col-md-3 col-lg-2` doesn't work for you?

Comment: show us your code, or create a jsfiddle/codepen with your project

Comment: @JamieD77 after some research I figured out what you were talking about, and yes that did work for me with some tweaking. If you post an answer I will give you credit, otherwise I will answer my own question. =D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use `col-lg` to change the width of columns on large displays.. you can mix this with `col-md` to get different size columns on different screen sizes

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-9 col-lg-10"></div>
    <div class="col-md-3 col-lg-2"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks! I did not realize that you could have two different column sizes depending on display size! I always wondered what the difference between col-md and col-lg (etc.) where. Now I know!